# SendGrid Webhook Setup

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

we have a requirement to set up URLs for different environments  (DEV, Test, and Prod) to receive incoming webhook events from SendGrid. But, the Sendgrid UI only allows to set up of a URL to receive incoming events.

Also, our requirement is that we don't want to post incoming events to our production URL when we're testing & vice-versa.

Comment: Hi, the solution for this seems to be sub-users, i.e sub accounts.  You will otherwise only be able to handle one url.